# React router not rendering default route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to add a default page where the user first goes to when opening the site, but it is not rendering the default route. How can I fix this?
react router v6
Note: works fine without router so shouldnt be a component issue

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import AddNote from './components/noteDisplay/addNote/newNote.js'
import NoteDisplay from './components/noteDisplay/noteDisplay.js'
import secondPage from './components/secondPage/secondContainer.js'
const App = () => {

  return (
      
        <div className="App">
          <h1 className="app-title">My notes</h1>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Routes>

                <Route path='/second' component={secondPage}/>
                <Route path='*' component={NoteDisplay}/>

              </Routes>
            </div>

          </Router>

        </div> 


  );
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` v6 `Route` component API changed significantly from v5. Gone are the `component` prop and `render` and `children` function props, replaced by a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX.

[Routes & Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Switch from the old `Route` `component` prop to the `element` prop, and pass the routed component as JSX instead of a reference to the component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/second' element={<SecondPage />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<NoteDisplay />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-not-rendering-default-route]

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: @GeneralPleather It should certainly work. See the attached [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-not-rendering-default-route-2umvz).

Comment: oh i forgot to change one of the component into element

Comment: @GeneralPleather So just to confirm, you have your code working with the applied solution?

Comment: Yes I have Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The page user see first is the home page and specified with "/". To make it default you can use index prop of Route component like in the following

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/second' component={secondPage}/>
    <Route path='*' component={NoteDisplay}/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
  <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<><Header /><Home /></>} />          
      <Route path="/login" element={<><Login /></>} />
      <Route path="/checkout" element={<><Header /><Checkout /></>} />
  </Routes>
    </div>
</Router>
```